# Center image in square button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've had a look around and there aren't any solutions to doing this. Basically, the back to top button does function. I just need it to be a square and not allow the icon to spill out of it.

The icon does show when the page first loads for some reason too but if you scroll down then back up it is no longer at the top.

I just need the icon to fit within the button as a square and not show until the user scrolls down, or when they're at the top of the page.

Below is my code;

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("GlossaryTop").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("GlossaryTop").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
#GTop {
 display: none;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 4vh;
   right: 4vh;
   z-index: 99;
    width: 10%;
    padding: 1.25vh 2.5vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #32e591;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 0.5vh #bff442;
}

#GTop:hover {
  background-color: #bff442;
  border: solid 0.5vh #32e591;
}

.gtopicon {
   height: 8vh;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
   }
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="GTop" title="Go back to the top"><img class="gtopicon" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/emoji-one/104/upwards-black-arrow_2b06.png"></button>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure it's a quick fix but I'm just stuck with it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the icon a background image and use the following css rules to achieve what you want:

```
background-image: url('https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/emoji-one/104/upwards-black-arrow_2b06.png');
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

Here's the complete updated snippet:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("GlossaryTop").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("GlossaryTop").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
#GTop {
 display: none;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 4vh;
   right: 4vh;
   z-index: 99;
    width: 10%;
    padding: 1.25vh 2.5vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #32e591;
    background-image: url('https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/emoji-one/104/upwards-black-arrow_2b06.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 0.5vh #bff442;
}

#GTop:hover {
  background-color: #bff442;
  border: solid 0.5vh #32e591;
}

.gtopicon {
   height: 8vh;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
   }
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="GTop" title="Go back to the top"></button>
```